# Does replacing the Windows directory with the one in Windows.old effectively rollback the operating system?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I upgraded to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8. The blank screen came up (if someone could help me fix that, I would mark it as the accepted answer). Now I want to rollback.

I see the Windows.old directory contains a Windows folder. I'm guessing it was a backup of my Windows 8 system.

Can I replace the main Windows folder with the one inside Windows.old to effectively rollback the operating system?

Thanks.

**P.S.:** I am asking this question on Windows 7, which is on another partition on the same drive on the same computer as the Windows 8.1 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft explained here in detail how to us Windows.old to restore Windows to an older version:

**How to restore a Windows 7-based computer to a previous Windows installation by using the Windows.old folder**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971760

You also have to fix other folders like Users and "Program Files". But I have never tried it.